# type date - input using only calendar picker HTML5

Tags: html

Is there any way not to allow to edit date manually? I mean that I would like to force user to pick date using only calendar.

Having

```
<input type="date"   value="yyyy-mm-dd" class="input-medium search-query">
```

user can type in something into input form. I have tried to do this way:

```
<input type="date"   value="yyyy-mm-dd" class="input-medium search-query" disabled>
```

but it frozen the whole form.

Any hints?
Or maybe is there any fast way to prevent user to break date format?
(Because I use bootstrap I would not prefer to use jquery)

Comment: It may not be possible, but why take away this possibility in the first place?

Comment: 1. You're damaging your own page's UX by removing basic UI that an user would expect; 2. You will simply turn your page unusable to browsers that do not support `date` inputs; 3. Do proper validation instead of relying on a client-side thing that can be easily bypassed.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté +1 thanks for good remarks. Indeed,  validation seems to be a better solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could return false when the user presses a key, if your prepared to throw a bit of JS in there:

```
<input type="date"   value="yyyy-mm-dd" class="input-medium search-query" onkeypress="return false">
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Axh6E/)

Comment: is there a way to display whole name of month like January?

Comment: `onkeypress="return false"` doesn't prevent backspace but `onkeydown="return false"` does

Answer (score 0):

In old browsers, type=date is not supported and will degrade to type=text. Then, the onkeydown='return false' method will make input impossible.